# How can you automate copying a report on an SSRS Report server?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2014

Right now we use linked reports in many places.  This causes subreports to link back to the original folder.

Is there a good way to copy a report in SSRS to copy a report to another folder with C#.  We don't want to manually open a report and save as to the folder where the linked item is.

Alternatively: is there a way to make subreport links appear like they're in the same location as the linked report?

Answer (score 1):

If your link is pointing to report /xxx/A and you want to move it to /yyy/A then you have to manually re-create the links or use the ReportService api to programmatically create the links.